synthesizable encoder (non-priority) using system verilog for loop
I have a table of 16 entries where each entry is 4 bits wide. There is a 4 bit input search vector that i have to find in the table and then return the row number of the matched entry. The entries are all unique, so, there will only be a single match.
The RTL i am currently using is:
logic [3:0] table_row[16];
logic [4:0] matched_row_num;

always_comb 
begin
  matched_row == 16; // default value if there is no actual match
  for (int i=15; i>=0; i--)
    begin
      if (in[3:0] == table_row[i])
        matched_row == i;
    end
end


Will this synthesize to a priority encoder like structure?
If yes, how do i code it using a for (or generate) to get a non-priority encoder?

The reason for using a for loop is the table depth is actually parameterizable and hence i would like this logic to be modular. That is the reason, i am not using a case statement.
I do not have access to a free synthesis tool that supports system verilog. So, i couldnt verify my assumptions.

You can OR the results together
always_comb 
begin
  matched_row == 16; // default value if there is no actual match
  foreach(table_row[i])
    if (in[3:0] == table_row[i]) begin
        matched_row[4] == 0;
        matched_row |= i;
    end

